# Filter Value x in CSV Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter the AREA field.
I only want to see data of AREA DE F2

How can I do this? I've searched Google.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjF3t.png)

Comment: add code and result to question body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
df.loc[df['AREA'] == 'DE F2']
```

you have the .loc[] in the wrong position